# Le tecnologie si "applicano" o si "usano"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Una tecnologia "si applica" o "si usa"?
*Usare* ha un significato più materiale (si "usa" un martello)

> a) "La tecnologia X si usa nel contesto Y"

> b) "La tecnologia X si applica nel contesto Y"

Quale tra le due frasi è più corretta?

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entrambe le cose; ad esempio, la tecnologia BlueTooth si *usa* per trasferire dati e si *applica* (o si usa, non vedo perché no) nel campo delle telecomunicazioni.

Fra l'altro, non concordo con il fatto che "usare" abbia di per sé un significato più materiale; ad esempio, si usa la ragione, si usa cortesia, si usa la violenza, etc.

Dal vocabolario Treccani:

[usare](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/usare/): 1. tr. a. Fare uso, servirsi di qualcosa, o anche di qualcuno, sia per una particolare  utilizzazione o finalità, sia abitualmente[...omissis...]

[applicare](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/applicare/): applicare v. tr. [dal lat. applicare, comp. di ad- e plicare «piegare», quindi propr. «inclinare, accostare»] (io àpplico, tu àpplichi, ecc.). – [...omissi...] 2. [...omissis...] d. Impiegare, destinare, dedicare: a. una persona a un ufficio; a. una messa a qualcuno o per qualcuno, celebrarla per conto di persona viva o in suffragio di un defunto.[...omissis...]

Comment: Su usare credo sia più contestualizzata la definizione successiva, sempre di Treccani: `In unione con termini astratti, adoperare nel proprio comportamento, nel proprio agire` 
Un atecnologia non è un "qualcosa", ma un termine astratto. (Ti sto dando ragione, eh)

Comment: Sì, in realtà fa parte della stessa definizione (significato 1); devo aver cancellato quella parte inavvertitamente, insieme agli esempi.

Comment: Una nota a proposito della natura concreta o astratta di "tecnologia": a mio avviso, se parliamo di "tecnologia" in senso generale parliamo di un concetto astratto ma se parliamo di una tecnologia particolare (ad esempio, la tecnologia laser, la tecnologia BlueTooth) parliamo di un concetto concreto, anche se immateriale. Comunque la questione è aperta ad interpretazioni soggettive, come si può leggere a questo link, sempre da Treccani: https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/nomi-concreti_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/ ;)